# Can you modify an object's field every time another field is modified?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-class

I have a dataclass that looks like this

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str | None = None
    file_friendly_name: str | None = field(default=None, init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        # If name, automatically create the file_friendly_name
        if self.name:
            self.file_friendly_name = "".join(
                i for i in self.name if i not in "/:*?<>|"
            )
```

If user passes `name` on instantiation, `file_friendly_name` is automatically created.

Is there a way to do it so that every time `name` is updated/changed, `file_friendly_name` also changes?

e.g.

```py
data = Data()
data.name = 'foo/bar'
print(data.file_friendly_name) # want: 'foobar'

data = Data(name='foo/bar')
data.name = 'new?name'
print(data.file_friendly_name) # want: 'newname'
```

Update based on answers:

1. I've tried setting `_name: str` and creating `name` using getters/setters. But I don't like how when you do `print(Data())` it shows `_name` as an attribute. I'd like that not to happen.
2. I like setting `file_friendly_name` as a property. But then you can't see that as an attribute when you do `print(Data())`. This is less of an issue but still not ideal.

Can it just show `name` and `file_friendly_name` as attributes when doing `print(Data())`?

Comment: codeananda as @matszwecja mentions below, it looks like your title and description are two different things. Did you originally want something to trigger every time you add an attribute to a class/instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest defining `file_friendly_name` as `@property` instead.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str | None = None
    
    @property
    def file_friendly_name(self) -> str | None:
        if self.name is not None:
            return "".join(
                i for i in self.name if i not in "\/:*?<>|"
            )
        else:
            return None

    def __repr__(self):
        fields_str = [f'{field.name}={getattr(self, field.name)!r}'
                      for field in fields(self)]
        fields_str.append(f'file_friendly_name={self.file_friendly_name}')
        fields_res = ', '.join(fields_str)
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({fields_res})'
```

Comment: this doesn't change the "file_friendly_name" field, it actually _recalculates_ the `file_friendly_name` property every time that property is invoked. in some contexts this extra computation can be problematic when a simple field access is within reach.

Comment: This is nice. But if I do `print(Data())` it doesn't show `file_friendly_name` as one of the params. Is there a way to do that as well? Come to think of it, it's probably not necessary (since the user is unlikely to use `file_friendly_name`... but still curious

Comment: @codeananda You could override `__str__` method to include `file_friendly_name` in the output

Comment: Great idea! Can you add that to your answer?

Comment: @codeananda Updated. You could also generalize it for any number of fields with `dataclasses.fields(self)`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I don't quite follow how to do that. Do I not still need to manually write out which fields I want to overwrite? Can you also add that to answer?

Comment: @codeananda Updated. Now you can add fields to `Data` and they'll all be printed

Comment: @ZevAverbach "30% slower than it needs to be" - that is simply incorrect. Sure, you do get faster getter on the property, but you need to perform an additional method call each time you try to change the value of `name`. If setter calls heavily outweigh getter calls your solution will be actually slower, not to mention the added memory of storing derived data along with the original `name`. As long as performance does not become an actual issue, I'd weigh heavily towards @Yevhen's solution, as it's lighter on memory.

Comment: @matszwecja i've removed this claim, thanks for pushing back on it: indeed, when using the exact examples from OP the performance isn't very different at all between our solutions.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych this works for `print` but not for `pprint`... any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @codeananda replace `__str__` with `__repr__`.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, there is a way!

## Code

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Data:
    _name: str | None = None
    file_friendly_name: str | None = field(default=None, init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        # If _name is not None, automatically create the file_friendly_name
        if self._name is not None:
            self.file_friendly_name = "".join(
                i for i in self._name if i not in "/:*?<>|"
            )

    @property
    def name(self) -> str | None:
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, new_val: str | None) -> None:
        if self._name == new_val:
            return
        self._name = new_val
        if self._name is None:
            self.file_friendly_name = None
        else:
            self.file_friendly_name = "".join(
                i for i in self._name if i not in "/:*?<>|"
            )
```

## Explanation

Since you asked for a way to actually *update* the `file_friendly_name` field whenever `name` changes, I've changed the `name` field into a property which reads from private attribute `_name`. Now it's `_name` which is assessed in `__post_init__`.

Then I've created a "setter" for the `name` property. This setter will be called every time `name` is updated. Note that there's no sort of `Data.name.setattr(...)` boilerplate-y nonsense, given that we're in Python-land. When I say "updated", I mean whenever you do

```py
>>> d = Data("Zev")
>>> d.name = "**Zev**"
```

that setter will be invoked and the `name` and `file_friendly_name` fields will be updated accordingly:

```py
>>> d.file_friendly_name
'Zev'
>>> d.name
'**Zev**'

>>> data = Data()
>>> data.name = 'foo/bar'
>>> print(data.file_friendly_name) 
'foobar'

>>> data = Data('foo/bar')
>>> data.name = 'new?name'
>>> print(data.file_friendly_name) 
'newname'
```

## Pretty Printing

One small drawback of this is that printing `data` shows our private field:

```py
>>> print(data)
Data(_name='new?name', file_friendly_name='newname')
```

However, you can work around this by defining your own `__repr__` method:

```py
def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return f"Data(name='{self._name}', file_friendly_name='{self.file_friendly_name}')"
```

```py
>>> print(data)
Data(name='new?name', file_friendly_name='newname')
```

## Making `name` work in the constructor

Finally, if you'd like your `name` keyword argument back for constructing `Data` instances, you can add your own constructor to it. We'll DRY up the code this requires while we're at it:

```py
def __init__(self, name: str | None = None):
    self._name = name
    if self._name is not None:
        self.file_friendly_name = self.make_file_friendly_name(self._name)

def __post_init__(self):
    # If _name is not None, automatically create the file_friendly_name
    if self._name is not None:
        self.file_friendly_name = self.make_file_friendly_name(self._name)

@name.setter
def name(self, new_val: str | None) -> None:
    if self._name == new_val:
        return
    self._name = new_val
    if self._name is None:
        self.file_friendly_name = None
    else:
        self.file_friendly_name = self.make_file_friendly_name(self._name) #  revised
    

@staticmethod
def make_file_friendly_name(name: str) -> str:
    return "".join(
        i for i in name if i not in "\\/:*?<>|"
    )
```

After this, the sample code works as expected:

```py
>>> data = Data()
>>> data.name = 'foo/bar'
>>> print(data.file_friendly_name) 
'foobar'

>>> data = Data(name='foo/bar')
>>> data.name = 'new?name'
>>> print(data.file_friendly_name) 
'newname'
```

Comment: Nice solution! But changing `name` from `Zev` to `**Zev**` shouldn't change the `file_friendly_name` :) Pretty sure, your code is correct, but the usage example isn't reliable. Another small issue is that `Data(name='foo/bar')` would fail as `Data` doesn't have `name` in defined fields.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych thanks for the comment, but in fact OP requested 'Is there a way to do it so that every time name is updated/changed, file_friendly_name also changes?' So indeed, he wants `file_friendly_name` to change whenever `name` changes, it's the primary request! As for your second note, on the contrary my code works perfectly because the property `name` has a setter. EDIT: indeed, you have to leave out the keyword when instantiating `Data`, you're correct about that. A few extra lines would allow `name` as a keyword argument to the constructor, though!

Comment: @ZevAverbach I tried this method before but didn't like how if you do `print(data)` it shows `_name` as one of the attributes. Is there a way to get around that? Ideally it would just show `name` and `file_friendly_name`

Comment: @codeananda good question: indeed, there is. I'll add it to my answer, and you may want to add it to your question as well.

Comment: having updated my answer, `name` is again accepted as a keyword argument to `Data()`

Answer (score 2):

Similiarly to @Yevhen's suggestion, but using setter on property you can trigger a specific function when setting to an attribute. You can then check if class has related private attribute to tell if you are definining it right now or it already exists.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

def methodToTrigger():
    print("Triggered method")

@dataclass
class Data:
    name: str = None

    def __post_init__(self):
        # If name, automatically create the file_friendly_name
        if self.name:
            self.file_friendly_name = "".join(
                i for i in self.name if i not in "\/:*?<>|"
            )
    @property
    def file_friendly_name(self):
        return self._file_friendly_name

    @file_friendly_name.setter
    def file_friendly_name(self, value):
        if not hasattr(self, "_file_friendly_name"):
            methodToTrigger()
        self._file_friendly_name = value

d = Data(name = "asdf")

print(d.file_friendly_name)
```

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I actually slightly misread the question. My answer is OP asked for (mostly in the title), yours is what he actually needs :P (classic X/Y problem)

Comment: this is still very helpful! Do you have a suggestion for how I could rephrase the title to more match my question?